# Create Countdown Timer for Excel Ribbon

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, ribbon, countdowntimer

I am looking to create a countdown timer for a ribbon in excel using VSTO when button1 is clicked.

Here is my code so far:

```
private void Ribbon1_Load(object sender, RibbonUIEventArgs e)
{
    TimerLabel.Label = "5:00";
    Convert.ToInt32(TimerLabel.Label);

}

private void button1_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
{
    TimeSpan TimeDecrease = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);\
    TimerLabel.Label = Convert.ToInt32(TimerLabel.Label) - TimeDecrease;
}
```

}

Not to sure how to go about it. Any help is great

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the code for Ribbon.cs

```
    private TimeSpan startTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(0,5,0,0);
    private Timer timer = new Timer();
  public void Ribbon_Load(Office.IRibbonUI ribbonUI)
    {
        timer.Interval = 1000;
        this.ribbon = ribbonUI;
        timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
        timer.Start();
    }

    private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TimeSpan timeDecrease = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
        startTimeSpan = startTimeSpan - timeDecrease;
        ribbon.InvalidateControl("timerLabel");
    }

    public string timerLabel_getLabel(Office.IRibbonControl control)
    {
        return startTimeSpan.ToString();
    }

    //public void button1_onAction(Office.IRibbonControl control)
    //{
    //    timer.Start();
    //}
```

Here is Ribbon.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customUI onLoad="Ribbon_Load" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" >
    <ribbon>
        <tabs>
            <tab id="TimerTest" label="Timer">
                <group id="group1" label="group1">
                    <labelControl id="timerLabel" getLabel="timerLabel_getLabel"/>
                    <button id="button1" label="button1" showImage="false" onAction="button1_onAction" />
                </group>
            </tab>
        </tabs>
    </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

Comment: i have 'Ribbon1.InvalidateControl("timerlabel");' , but it says does not contain a definition for "InvalidateControl".

Comment: It is in namespace Microsoft.Office.Core http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.core.iribbonui.invalidatecontrol

Comment: I got that to work, but the time only goes down by a 1 second increment when i press it, which means i have to keep pressing it. Any ideas ? Also how would i make this start on startup without the button

Comment: thanks for that edit. The last question is that i am now getting this error - "The type or namespace name 'Timer' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
"

Comment: Use this namespace using System.Windows.Forms;

Comment: thanks, but this still doesnt run on start-up, it still requires the button to be pressed

Comment: Copied timer.Start() to Ribbon Load event, check the edited code

Comment: ok edited the code added timer.Interval = 1000; in Ribbonload